# connecting to a service broadcasted by pyzeroconf is refused

Tags: python, sockets, networking, zeroconf

I setup a zeroconf with pyzeroconf (https://github.com/jstasiak/python-zeroconf/):

```
TYPE = "_motion._tcp.local."
NAME = "_yyyyXXXX." + TYPE
PORT = 4321

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("zeroconf").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

zeroconf = Zeroconf()

def reg_srv():
    info = ServiceInfo(TYPE,
            NAME,
            socket.inet_aton("127.0.0.1"), PORT, 0, 0,
            {"desc":"HOME Bonjour test"})


    zeroconf.register_service(info)
```

I use `nc -l 4321` to receive connection.

But socket ( from a remote computer or phone ) reported connection refused.

When I turned to use `dns-sd -R "XXX" "_motion._tcp" "local" 4321` it work well.

What am I missing ?

--- updated:

I found it was due to `socket.inet_aton("127.0.0.1")`. if I changed it with my LAN ip address it can work.

But how should I set this address value to suit a dynamic ip address ?

--- updated:

I changed with:

```
socket_addr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
info = ServiceInfo(TYPE,
        NAME,
        socket.inet_aton(socket_addr), PORT, 0, 0,
        {"desc":"HOME Bonjour test"})
```

how to support ipv4 and ipv6 address simultaneously ?

with `socket.getaddrinfo()` to get multiple addresses and each registers one service ?